# How to group rows by a column and erase unneeded rows?

Tags: excel

Each row has a name, some names appear on multiple rows. I am trying to have Excel look at the name and if there is a duplicate for that name, then look at that action date and only keep the row with the most recent action date, and delete the other rows. The name may contain two or more rows with the same action date. For the example I would need Excel to keep only the rows:

```
Abendroth, Jacqueline 1/12/15;
Abendroth, Jacqueline 1/12/15;
Allen, Christopher Ashely 04/25/14;
Anantpadma, Manu 09/09/14
```

Here's some example rows.

```
----------
Name    Action Dt
----------
Abendroth,Jacqueline    01/12/15 12:00 AM
----------
Abendroth,Jacqueline    01/12/15 12:00 AM
----------
Abendroth,Jacqueline    12/02/14 12:00 AM
----------
Allen,Christopher Ashley    04/25/14 12:00 AM
----------
Allen,Christopher Ashley    04/10/14 12:00 AM
----------
Anantpadma,Manu 09/09/14 12:00 AM
----------
Anantpadma,Manu 08/07/14 12:00 AM
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Name` is in A1, then in say D2:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))
```

and E2:

```
=B2=D2
```

both copied down to suit. Then filter ColumnE to select and delete rows showing `FALSE`.

The MAX formula requiring array entry (ie with Ctrl+Shift+Enter).